# Javascript recursion function async-await for generating tree

Tags: javascript, recursion, async-await, treeview

I'm trying to generate this structure of html tree(I used a clothes shop for example)

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li><span class="caret">Kids cloths</span>
        <ul class="nested">
            <li>Boys</li>
            <li>Girls</li>
            <li><span class="caret">Dresses</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li><span class="caret">Maxi dresses</span>
                        <ul class="nested">
                            <li>dress 1</li>
                            <li>dress 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span class="caret">Mini dresses</span>
                        <ul class="nested">
                            <li>dress 3</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><span class="caret">Shirts</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li>shirt 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**

There can be an empty category(like "Boys"), and nested categories(Girls->Dresses->Maxi dresses).
Finally I want to get to some product and display its page.

The API that I get, alךow me to send a category name, and get all its subcategories.
For example: getSubCategories(Kids cloths)-> will give me : Boys, Girls.(both are categories)
getSubCategories(Girls)-> will give me : Dresses, Shirts. (both are categories)
getSubCategories(Shirts)->will give me: shirt 1. (a product)

my code look like this:

```
function getSubCategories(CategoryName){
    let fetchPromise = fetch(queryTextForAPI).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      });

      return fetchPromise;
}

async function build_category_tree_recursive(root_category){
  let subcategories =await getSubCategories(root_category)
  let data=subcategories.query.categorymembers;
  if(data.length>0){
      data.forEach(element=>{
          if(element.type==="subcat"){//this is a category
              (async () => {
                let son_node=await build_category_tree_recursive(element.title);
                //I'm not sure what to do here?
                //How to generate a html code and concatenate it to "myUL"? 
              })();

          }
          else if(element.type==="page"){//it's a product
              return element.title;
          }
      });
  }
  else{
      //return the full htl that was generated?
  }
}
```

getSubCategories("Kids cloths") is not giving me the html that I want.(I deleted from the codes my tryes to generate the html, and I left the basic function)

I tried to concatenate the results from the build_category_tree_recursive calls- But it was all messed up.
I also tried to build a node class, and add a child in every call, but it didn't work either.
I'm missing something here, Maybe it has something to do with a recursion understanding, maybe to async-await understanding, maybe for both of them.
I'll really appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the json responses from getSubCategories

Comment: @THEAMAZING, thank you very much for wanting to help!
Scott Sauyet already gave me a solution that works for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by transforming the data into a single object.  From there we can do a separate step to format this as HTML.

This solution involves mutual recursion, which simplifies a number of problems.  Our main function, `getStructure` calls your `getSubCategories` function but also calls a simple `getAllSubCats` function.  That one in turn calls `getStructure` on the relevant children.

Here's one implementation of that (with a dummy version of `getSubCategories`.)

```js
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Main object fetching code
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const getAllSubCats = async (categories) =>
  Promise .all (categories .map (
    ({type, title}) => type == 'subcat' ?  getStructure (title) : {title}
  ))

const getStructure = async (title) => {
  const children = await getSubCategories (title)
  const subCategories = await getAllSubCats (children)
  return {title, subCategories}
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// HTML formatting code
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const sp = (indent) => ' '.repeat(4 * indent)

const formatTree = ({title = '', subCategories = []}, indent) => 
  subCategories.length
    ? `${sp(indent)}<li><span class="caret">${title}</span>
${sp(indent + 1)}<ul class="nested">
${subCategories.map(subcat => formatTree(subcat, indent + 2)).join('\n')}
${sp(indent + 1)}</ul> 
${sp(indent)}</li>`
    : `${sp(indent)}<li>${title}</li>`

const formatHtml = (tree) => `<ul id="myUL">\n${formatTree(tree, 1)}\n</ul>`

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Demo code
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

getStructure ('Kids clothes')
  .then(logObj)
  .then(formatHtml)
  .then(console.log)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Fake implementation for demo
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const getSubCategories = ((cats) => async (name) => 
  Promise.resolve(name in cats ? cats[name] : [])
)({
    'Kids clothes': [{title: 'Boys', type: 'subcat'}, {title: 'Girls', type: 'subcat'}],
    Boys: [],
    Girls: [{title: 'Dresses', type: 'subcat'}, {title: 'Shirts', type: 'subcat'}],
    Dresses: [{title: 'Maxi dresses', type: 'subcat'}, {title: 'Mini dresses', type: 'subcat'}],
    'Maxi dresses': [{title: 'dress 1', type: 'page'}, {title: 'dress 2', type: 'page'}],
    'Mini dresses': [{title: 'dress 3', type: 'page'}],
    Shirts: [{title: 'shirt 1', type: 'page'}],
})

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Helper function for demo
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

const logObj = (obj) => console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4)) || obj
</script>
```

The HTML generation should be fairly straightforward.  The only thing somewhat unusual is the use of the `indent` and the `sp`, the space-generating function.  This is very useful in debugging, but in the end, I would probably use these versions for production:

```js
const formatTree = ({title = '', subCategories = []}) => 
  subCategories.length
    ? `<li><span class="caret">${title}</span><ul class="nested">`
      + subCategories.map(subcat => formatTree(subcat)).join('') 
      + `</ul></li>`
    : `<li>${title}</li>`

const formatHtml = (tree) => `<ul id="myUL">${formatTree(tree, 1)}</ul>`
```

While such a breakdown into separate object-generation and formatting steps is not essential, it usually makes problems like this much simpler.

Note that this doesn't quite match your requested output.  I think there was an issue with your version, as it doesn't nest "dresses" under "Girls" even though your sample responses structured it that way.

Also, you will probably need to reconfigure the object generation to how the actual responses look.  I don't even try to match, just going for something simple.

Finally, there is no error checking here.  We assume any request succeeds.  You would probably need actual error checking in your real app.  I leave that to you.

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I needed!
Thank you so much!
1.I have to admit I'm really jealous!
I would never have been able to write such a code!
I know JS is a new topic for me, and I have a lot to learn.
Maybe you have some tips for me and recommended resources to learn from?

2. And I have another question about the solution. A little silly, I admit.
How do I get the getStructure function to return the tree and not write it to console.log?
So I can read it from another page and use getElementByID to init my div with the returned html string? I tried assign it and got "promise pending"

Comment: `getStructure` as implemented here does not write to `console.log`.  It returns a Promise that will resolve to that object value.  The demo code calls `getStructure('root category').then(console.log)`.  But you can call `getStructure('foo').then(yourFunction)` here where `yourFunction` accepts the structure and does something with it.  Because this depends upon asynchronous calls, you cannot make it simply synchronous, although if you have an `async` function you can make it looks that way with `const categories = await getStructure('foo'); // now do something with categories`.

Comment: As to learning, the best teacher, as always is experience.  Keep plugging away at it, looking things up and asking questions when you get stuck.  If you learn well from written material, then the best beginner/intermediate JS book I know of is Marijn Haverbeke's [Eloquent JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/).  I'd also highly recommend Reg Braithwaite's [JavaScript Allonge](https://leanpub.com/javascriptallongesix/read), and Brian Lonsdorf's [Mostly Adequate Guide...](https://mostly-adequate.gitbooks.io/mostly-adequate-guide/), but both are for more advanced readers.